# Css :contains after Ajax loaded script append

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to do `$('td:contains("text")').css('color','red')` after Ajax load script

main code

```
<div id="datatable"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script id="body">$(document).ready(function(){$.ajax({url:"script.js",type:"POST",cache:!1,success:function(c){c&&$("#body").append(c)}})});$('td:contains("text")').css('color','red');alert("script")</script>
```

code script.js

```
var datatable = document.getElementById("datatable");
var table = "<table><tr><td id='tdone'>Text</td></tr>" + 
      "<tr><td id='tdtwo'>Two</td></tr></table>";
datatable.appendChild(table);

alert("code");
```

I can't get the code working as `Script` alert appears first then `code` alert.

So how to wait until ajax load and append table to document and when fire script?

Nor Success nor Complete, nor find, nor ajaxStop methods not works

Comment: this is the problem i think. $("td:contains("text")") doble quotes problem, escape them with /

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="datatable"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="your-path-to-script.js/script.js"></script>
<script id="body">
$(document).ajaxStop({
   $('td:contains("text")').css('color','red');alert("script");
});
</script>
```

Fore more : https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: try to include your jquery code before `script.js` include

Comment: Script alert goes first when goes COde alert, not work

Comment: why dont you just include the script instead of using ajax? See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

For appending this css `$("td:contains("text")").css('color','red')` it has to go inside ajax success callback function inside of writing this logic outside.Like:

```
success:function(c){
    $("#body").append(c);
    $("td:contains("text")").css('color','red')
}
```

Comment: Have you try debugging and saw whether the call is going inside ajax callback?

Comment: yes, and place alerts too, but always appears `script` alert first, which says what table not appended yet

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the success block of the Ajax function to execute code after the Ajax completes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"script.js",
    type:"POST",
    cache:false,
    success:function(c){
        c&&$("#body").append(c);
        $("td:contains(\"text\")").css('color','red');
        alert("script");
        //Whatever you put here runs after Ajax Completes
    }
  });
  //This runs before Ajax Complete
});
```

Additionally, you need to escape your inner double quotes as you cannot have nested quotes of the same kind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the specific color of td then

```
$.ajax({
    url:"URL ",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(Response){
        $("tr > nth-child(1)").css("color","red");
        //Whatever you put here runs after Ajax Completes
    }
  });
```

If You want give color by selected row then Just give Id to that row and pass that id to function

If you want to change the specific color of td then

```
$.ajax({
    url:"URL",
    type:"POST",
    success:function(Response){
        $("#id td : nth-child(1)").css("color","red");
        //Whatever you put here runs after Ajax Completes
    }
  });
```

By this Way you can sort this problem.